# Random numbers with exponentiated gamma distribution?

Tags: density-function, gamma-distribution, random-generation

How to get random numbers following "exponentiated gamma distribution"?
I tried to search some functions in R
and this is what i got:
https://rdrr.io/cran/Newdistns/man/expg.html

I want to know the exact code for generating random numbers following "exponentiated gamma distribution".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you have installed the package Newdistns (the one you have linked to). If necessary, install it with

```
install.packages("Newdistns")
```

Then:

```
library(Newdistns)
rexpg(10, "gamma", a = 1, shape = 1)
```

This will give you 10 random samples from the exponentiated gamma distribution with shape 1. Note, that while `a` is the shape parameter of the exponentiation, the `shape = 1` refers to the shape of the gamma distribution. In fact, all the parameters you want to be used on the gamma function must follow after all the parameters for the `rexpg()` function, in this case, after the `a=1` argument.

Comment: thanx frank. What does a and shape really mean in real life, other than changing the shape of the distribution. In poisson, lambda would mean rate of something per period or area. In exponential distribution, the parameter has the meaning of time till 1st event. In such case of exponentiated gamma ditribution, where we give the r-function, a shape and "a," what would be their real life meaning?